# How can I make def function that have same effect with Counter class?

Tags: python, function, counter

I want to make def function which have same effect with Counter class and It's most_common function.
And I success to make def function to find only the mode of a string like this way.

```py
def most_common_char_count(s):
    dict = {}
    for n in s:
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
    return dict

str1 = 'dajklvkdafjkd;ajfeqipjjfdas;fjkdsal;'
most_commons = most_common_char_count(str1) 
print(most_common_char_count(str1))
```

But I want to add most_command function to this def function. Like this is a program that can print up to the nth order of frequency. So I made an algorithm for the program, but I don't know how to implement it. The algorithm is as follows.

```py
def most_common_char_count(s, n=None): #it have two parameters
    dictionary = {} #and I made string in dictionary
    for n in s:
        if n == None: #If n==none, returns the entire dictionary as a list of tuples
            dictionary[n] += 1
            return(list(zip(dict.keys(),dict.values())))
        else: #Returns the n most frequent items as a list of tuples.
            
s = 'dajklvkdafjkd;ajfeqipjjfdas;fjkdsal;'
most_commons = most_common_char_count(s, 4) 
print(4, most_commons)
print(most_common_char_count(s))
```

So if I put `print(4, most_commons)`, output will be

```
[('j', 6), ('d', 5), ('a', 5), ('k', 4)]
```

I don't know what code to write in the else statement. And if there are any additional errors, please let me know.

Comment: FYI you can just write `if n in dict`, you don't need `dict.keys()`.

Comment: Convert the dictionary to a list of key/value tuples. Sort this by the counts, and return the slice with the first `n` elements.

Comment: YOu shouldn't do this in the loop. The loop needs to make the entire dctionary. Then at the end you extract the top N counts.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the dictionary, sort it by the counts and return the first `n` elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def most_common_char_count(s, n=None):
    counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for item in s:
        counts[item] += 1

    if n is None:
        return counts
    else:
        return dict(sorted(counts.entries(), key=lambda k, v: v, reverse=True)[:n])
```

Some other points:

1. Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type and function. I changed it to `counts`.
2. You can't use `n` as both the function parameter and the iteration variable in `for`.
3. You can use `defaultdict` instead of explicitly testing if the key is in the dictionary.